# Groovy - Count the recurrence of certain key in a list of maps or a map

Tags: groovy

I'm at beginning of programming so sorry if this is a stupid question.. :)

I'm trying to count the number of times a certain key is found in a list of maps or a map. (it can be either one)
In my example, I need to know the number of times key key1 will appear in a variable (keep in mind that it can be either a list of maps or a map)

```
def test01 = [[key1:'value1', key2:'value1', key3:'value1'], [key1:'value1', key2:'value1', key3:'value1'], [key5:'value1', key2:'value1', key4:'value1']]
def test02 = [key1:'value1', key2:'value1', key3:'value1']


def test03 = test01.findAll{it -> it.key1}.size()
println (test03)
```

My code works if my variable will be a list of maps (test01). But it brakes if I try it on a map (test02).. I'm not sure how to correctly iterate so it's ok for both a list of maps or a map.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
countKey = { e -> (e instanceof Map ? [e] : e).count { it.key1 } }

countKey(test01)
countKey(test02)
```